# preg_replace string with array

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Okay, so my question is pretty simple. I hope the answer is too.
Let's say I have the following php string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dynamicContent">
        <myTag>PART_ONE</myTag>
        <myTag>PART_TWO </myTag>
        <myTag> PART_THREE</myTag>
        <myTag> PART_FOUR </myTag>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say this is $content.
Now, you can see I have 4 custom tags (myTag) with one word content. (PART_ONE, PART_TWO, etc.)
I want to replace those 4 with 4 different strings. Those latter 4 strings are in an array:

```
$replace = array("PartOne", "PartTwo", "PartThree", "PartFour");
```

I did this but it doesn't work succesfully:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<myTag>(.*?)<\/myTag>/s", $replace, $content);
```

So, I want to search for myTags (it finds 4) and replace it with one entry of the array. The first occurrence should be replaced by $replace[0], the second by $replace[1], etc.
Then, it will return the "new" content as a string (not as an array) so I can use it for further parsing.

How should I realize this?

Comment: It would be much, much simpler to search for PART_ONE etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to tell that I do not know the value of myTag, so PART_ONE can just as good be "MY_ELEPHANT". I should be able to enter anything in the html template and then the code will see whatever is between the myTag tags.

Also, I don't think the saying "You can't parse html with regex" applies here, since I am not parsing the attributes of a tag, but just the value of a tag which is a simple and failsafe task for regex.

Comment: You could use preg_replace_callback() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
$replace = array("PartOne", "PartTwo", "PartThree", "PartFour");
if (preg_match_all("/(<myTag>)(.*?)(<\/myTag>)/s", $content, $matches)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $matches[1][$i] . $replace[$i] . $matches[3][$i], $content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to loop over each element in the array you want to replace with; replace the words `myTag` with `myDoneTag` or something for each one you finished, so you find the next one. Then you can always put back `myTag` at the end, and you have your string:

```
for(ii=0; ii<4; ii++) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<myTag>.*<\/myTag>/s", "<myDoneTag>".$replace[ii]."<\/myDoneTag>", $content, 1);
}
$content = preg_replace("/myDoneTag/s", "myTag", $content);
```

Comment: If the regex matches it will replace everything the first time, and not care about the other 3 loop iterations.

Comment: Hmm, although I already thought something like this would be the answer and accept it, I don't think it's wise to use this since it's basically a loop within a loop (preg_replace loops too) and thus this lags performance.

I guess if there's no other high performance solution I'll just go with (X)HTML parsing or something like that.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - you are right. Added the "limit" parameter and set it to 1 - "replace only the first instance".

Comment: @JohnSmith - I believe clarity should trump speed except when performance is really at a premium. You're going around this loop four times - and the regex will stop each time it finds the first match. Do you really think you get a measurable performance penalty?

Answer (score 0):

With regexes, you could something like this:

```
$replaces = array('foo','bar','foz','bax');
$callback = function($match) use ($replaces) {
        static $counter = 0;
        $return = $replaces[$counter % count($replaces)];
        $counter++;
        return $return;
};
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('/a/',$callback, 'a a a a a '));
```

But really, when searching for tags in html or xml, you want a parser:

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dynamicContent">
        <myTag>PART_ONE</myTag>
        <myTag>PART_TWO </myTag>
        <myTag> PART_THREE</myTag>
        <myTag> PART_FOUR </myTag>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);
$counter = 0;
foreach($d->getElementsByTagName('mytag') as $node){
        $node->nodeValue = $replaces[$counter++ % count($replaces)];
}
echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score -2):

This should be the syntax you're looking for:

```
$patterns = array('/PART_ONE/', '/PART_TWO/', '/PART_THREE/', '/PART_FOUR/');
$replaces = array('part one', 'part two', 'part three', 'part four');

preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $text);
```

But be warned, these are run sequentially so if the text for 'PART_ONE` contains the text 'PART_TWO' that will be subsequently replaced.

Comment: content of tags in source data is unknown